# Remove spacing between rows in UICollectionView? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How can I remove the spacing in between rows in a UICollection View? Only found methods to remove spacing between columns.
[image]

As you can see from the picture, there's a huge gap in between the rows. Is there a way to minimize this?

Current set up: via Storyboard, Layout: Flow, Scroll Direction: Verticle

The only other code I have the it is to make sure there will always be two columns regardless of screen size:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
          let padding: CGFloat =  50
          let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding

          return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: collectionViewSize)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout to get the section spacing

**collectionView(_:layout:insetForSectionAt:)**

> Asks the delegate for the margins to apply to content in the specified section.

**func collectionView(UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt: Int) -> CGFloat**

> Asks the delegate for the spacing between successive rows or columns of a section.

**func collectionView(UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt: Int) -> CGFloat**

> Asks the delegate for the spacing between successive items in the rows or columns of a section.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the solution. I needed to adjust the height in the code above:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
          let padding: CGFloat =  50
          let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding
//made adjustments to the height here
          return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: collectionViewSize - 80)
    }
```